# Story Identification: Movie with scary living trees from early 80s

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember seeing a big scary cardboard cutout of a tree in a video rental store in the early 1980s when I was a few years old. I haven't been able to find any information about it. I think I remember that the tree had a face, and two of its branches were like arms. I'm pretty sure this wasn't The Evil Dead. Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhenTreesAttack

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPuA0NTVDds? - Timescale completely wrong though.

Comment: Poltergeist had a possessed tree; http://ruggerjay.typepad.com/.a/6a00d8341cf11753ef014e86782263970d-800wi

Comment: I assume not these guys? http://youtu.be/8zQeQunbBmk?t=1m10s

It's way too early, 1960s, though.

Comment: @Richard I'm pretty sure it wasn't Poltergeist. If I saw a picture of the prop, I would recognize it. It was a pretty elaborate cardboard cutout.

Comment: Sounds like Day of the Triffids to me

Comment: If it was 1990 (instead of early 80s), might have been marketing for "The Guardian". The plot revolved around a druid who worshipped an evil-looking living tree.

Comment: @StevenWood It could possibly be Day of the Triffids. However, I'm not sure if there would be a display for such an old movie.

Comment: Here's a [simple search that](https://www.google.com/search?q=day+of+the+triffids+movie&rlz=1C1CHBF_enCA750CA750&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=AQYVyZseYK3ufM%253A%252Cktrg-kt46QTRXM%252C%252Fm%252F0f7__b&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kRtGEFwENa7_BFyXhfbdNU75lY5Bw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAmPS8ou7jAhVJSN8KHTQGCT8Q_B0wHnoECA0QAw#imgrc=AQYVyZseYK3ufM:) may help you figure it out.